# Anime with a girl who chooses a school based on its uniform and ends up in a club with duels and special powers

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic

The female lead chooses a school based on its uniform, and the school she chose was a kind of unusual one where the students are required to join a club and have a duel with one another, and everyone there seems to have some type of special power.

She also sees a blond boy in a painting club. She has difficulties choosing a club and ends up in go home club, but eventually, she gets into a gaming club where she could use some gaming equipment.

There is also another black-haired girl character (the female lead chooses her school by seeing her).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You've tagged this "magic" and you say the students have "abilities" but can you clarify what this means?  Can you name any specific powers that characters have?  So far you haven't identified any elements that would make this question on-topic for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about scifi or fantasy.

Comment: @AndresF. Given the "magic" tag, I would assume that "everyone there seems to have some type of ability" which is magical, making the question on-topic. But this could really use some clarification from OP.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. Girls schools rarely make the students compete in duels.

Comment: @Laurel fair enough! I've edited the question to reword "abilities" (which is ambiguous) to "special powers", which is how several wikis describe this anime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*Mikagura School Suite*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/28817/Mikagura_Gakuen_Kumikyoku_TV) (AKA *Mikagura Gakuen Kumikyoku*).

> To be around cute girls wearing cute clothing is all Eruna Ichinomiya desires. Since Mikagura High School happens to have the cutest uniforms around, she decides to enroll in this prestigious high school known for its cultural clubs.
>
> However, she does not realize that joining a club is mandatory, and representatives from each club must battle for a ranking. Based on these rankings, club members are awarded housing and food. Chasing after Seisa Mikagura, the most beautiful girl in school, Eruna joins the going-home club but finds herself thrust into fighting the next club battle. With the other club representatives wielding unique powers, the competition is sure to be fierce!

Comment: Omg!!! Tysm i was searching for the for so long...